# how to make login page like instagram in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi all i want to create a login page like instagram specially rectangle Username and password with user icon and password key icon in username and password field respectively.

I have searched a lot and didn't find anything. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

#### Update Answer:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_email"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usericon_m"
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_b"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:singleLine="true"
    style="@style/uiEditText"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:textColor="@color/white" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_password"
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_m"
    android:background="@drawable/login_b"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true"
    style="@style/uiEditText"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:textColor="@color/white" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/get_login"
    style="@style/uiButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:text="@string/get_login"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use corner property.i.g.

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="##6fd02b" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip"            android:bottom="0dip" />

</shape>
```

Comment: no its not what i am looking for but any way thanks.

Comment: use drawable in edit text. android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"

Comment: i am almost near to goal one thing i am not able to increase the height of the field of username and password. @Mobeen Altaf

Comment: why? android:layout_height="70dp" it is not working.

Comment: i can't find any height parameter in EditText.but button have and parent layout have.like  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: that is solved now that hint is not coming parallel to userIcon

Comment: it is due to bottom .set gravity only center_vertical.

Answer (score 1):

In your code write:

```
myEditText.setCompoundDrawables(myDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Where myEditText is your EditText field and myDrawable is a picture you want to insert. If you want your picture at right side - write:

```
myEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, myDrawable);
```

In XML use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/myDrawable"` and `android:drawableRight="@drawable/myDrawable"` respectively.